# Cannot start X on my computer at all

Tags: graphics, live-usb, amd-graphics, 17.10, live-environment

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwnc8.jpg

This is from a verified Live USB running Ubuntu 17.10 Artful. 
Specs are as follows
- Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 board
- AMD FX-8350
- Powercolor PCS HD7870 MYST
- 8GB Corsair Vengeance DDR3

Can see boot logo just fine, but as soon as X starts, I get whatever leftover mess that's in the GPU RAM plastered on my screen. When rebooting from Windows, it's my login screen as shown. When cold, it's either garbage, black, or slightly more destroyed Windows, depending on time left off.

When this happens, I cannot move to another TTY. It will flash like this for about ten minutes, then will show some text as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSIt0.jpg

I can provide whatever other info you need. Card was tested on Windows, and works without error on Furmark. Was tested for 4 hours with no artifacing or crash.

Comment: What happens if you let the computer (and graphics card) get warm at the bootloader's screen (syslinux menu or grub menu)?

Comment: Garbage still. The whole "different garbage" tends to be about something requesting the render of specific GPU RAM regions, and it returning RAM that hasn't been written to (these "rings" that are being referred to refer to r̶e̶g̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶G̶P̶U̶ ̶R̶A̶M̶ different privilege levels, 0 being where it can write to the framebuffer directly. It's receiving calls to render the framebuffer, but X isn't able to write to that framebuffer, it's timing out.)

Comment: There are problems with the driver for the graphics card. Are there problems already when you run live (booted from the USB pendrive)? Or could you install and get problems with the installed system? Did you try with the boot option `nomodeset` ? See this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and links from it.

Comment: For people reaching this page, I never found a solution, even after trying newer kernels, so I gave up and got a different card. Seems the issue was isolated to just this particular card from this particular vendor.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) It would be helpful if you tell us which graphics card you are using, if you need some boot option, and if you use a built-in linux driver or a proprietary driver. Please tell us also which version of Ubuntu you are running now (for example 18.04.1 LTS).